# linux - batch move files into a directory and rename those files according to sequential syntax in that directory

Tags: bash, batch-rename, mv

I have two directories - A and B - that contain a bunch of photo files. Directory A is where I keep photos long-term, and the files inside are sequentially named "Photo-1.jpg, Photo-2.jpg, etc.".

Directory B is where I upload new photos to from my camera, and the naming convention is whatever the camera names the file. I figured out how to run some operations on Directory B to ensure everything is in .jpg format as needed (imagemagik convert), remove duplicate files (fdupes), etc.

My goal now is to move the files from B to A, and end up with the newly-added files in A sequentially named according to A's naming convention described above.

I know how to move the files into A, and then to batch rename everything in A after the new files have been added (which would theoretically occur every night), but I'm guessing there must be a more efficient way of moving the files from B to A without re-naming all 20,000+ photos every night, just because a few new files were added.

I guess my question is two parts - 1) I found a solution that works (us mv to rename all photos every night), is there any downside to this? and 2) If there is a downside and a more elegant method exists, can anyone help with a script that would look at whatever the highest number that exists in A, then re-name the files, appending onto that number, in B as they are moved over to A?

Thank you!

Comment: use timestamp for file names otherwise you won't know which files from B are already existing in A (because of excessive renaming) or do you want to run fdupes on A every day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `bash` script will only move and rename the new files from `DiretoryB` into your `DirectoryA` path. It also handles file names with spaces and/or any other odd characters in their name in `DirectoryB`

```
#!/bin/bash

aPath="./photos-A"
bPath="./photos-B"
aPattern="Photo-"

lNum=$(find $aPath -type f -name "*.jpg" -printf "%f\n" | \
  awk -F'[-.]' '{if($2>m)m=$2}END{print m}')
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' photo; do
        mv "$photo" "$aPath/$aPattern$((++lNum)).jpg"
done < <(find $bPath -type f -name "*.jpg" -print0)
```

#### Note

The command to find the last numbered photo, aka `$lNum` *will* run over all 20K+ files, but it should be fairly quick.  If it's not, you can always run this once and store the latest number into a file and read from that file.

#### Proof of Concept

```
$ tree photos-A/
photos-A/
├── Photo-1.jpg
├── Photo-2.jpg
├── Photo-3.jpg
├── Photo-5.jpg
├── Photo-6.jpg
├── Photo-7.jpg
└── Photo-8.jpg

0 directories, 7 files

$ tree photos-B/
photos-B/
├── bar.jpg
├── baz\ with\ spaces.jpg
└── foo.jpg

0 directories, 3 files

$ ./mvphoto.sh

$ tree photos-A/
photos-A/
├── Photo-10.jpg
├── Photo-11.jpg
├── Photo-1.jpg
├── Photo-2.jpg
├── Photo-3.jpg
├── Photo-5.jpg
├── Photo-6.jpg
├── Photo-7.jpg
├── Photo-8.jpg
└── Photo-9.jpg

0 directories, 10 files
```

Comment: Hmmm...I'm getting this error:                                                                                            /home/xixor/bin/photosort.sh: line 26: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/home/xixor/bin/photosort.sh: line 26: `done <(find $bPath -type f -name "*.jpg" -print0)'

Comment: @Xixor there are ***two*** `<` separated by a space as in `done < <(find ...)`

Comment: Sorry, thanks for your help. I mis-copied in my previous comment. I copy/pasted your exact code into my shell script, and keep getting - syntax error near unexpected token `<'

Comment: @Xixor since your error is saying line 26 and my script only has 11 lines, I suggest you copy my script as-is into its very own shell script file and convince yourself it works

Comment: Thank you, SiegeX! I copy/pasted your code exactly as you said into its own shell script file and it works perfectly. I am still mildly puzzled though; I previuosly had copy/pasted it into my other script (hence why you note the line 26 error), but I commented out everything before it so it theoretically should still have worked if everything before it was commented out, right? Thanks again though!

Comment: @Xixor glad it works for you now. Please accept the answer if everything meets your expectations.